# how to alter the case of a string in php? paSSw5ORD to PAssW5ord?

Tags: php, facebook, string, case

As mentioned in this [Meta Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26301/facebook-accepts-more-than-one-password), Facebook accepts the exact opposite case variation of our password. For example:

```
1.- paSSw5ORD  (Original password)
2.- PAssW5ord  (Case altered to exact opposite, Capital->Small and vice-versa.)
3.- PaSSw5ORD  (Only first letter's case altered)
```

How to get the second variation, provided the first one is the original one, entered by user (or to get first one when user enters second version)?
Here is my take on this.

```
<?php

$pass = "paSSw5ORD"; //Example password
$pass_len = strlen($pass); //Find the length of string

for($i=0;$i<$pass_len;$i++){
    if(!(is_numeric($pass[$i]))){                 //If Not Number
        if($pass[$i]===(strtoupper($pass[$i]))){  //If Uppercase
            $pass2 .= strtolower($pass[$i]);      //Make Lowercase & Append
        } else{                                   // If Lowercase
            $pass2 .= strtoupper($pass[$i]);      //Make Uppercase & Append
        }
    } else{                  //If Number
        $pass2 .= $pass[$i]; //Simply Append
    }
}

//Test both
echo $pass."\r\n";
echo $pass2;
?>
```

But how to make it process passwords with special characters (all possible on a standard English keyboard?

```
!@#$%^&*()_+|?><":}{~[];',./     (Space also)
```

This does not work on all above special characters.

```
if(preg_match('/^\[a-zA-Z]+$/', "passWORD")){
//Special Character encountered. Just append it and
//move to next cycle of loop, similar to when we
//encountered a number in above code. 
}
```

I am no expert of RegEx, so How to modify the above RegEx to make sure it processes all the above mentioned special characters?

Comment: Doesnot work means.. if there is a $ symbol in password, php just thinks its a variable name. echo "pas$word", php thinks i am asking it to echo pas+Value of $word..

Comment: @meze pas$word is just an example. $ sign can be anywhere in the string/user-password., received from a HTML form field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function to toggle case of characters in a string .

```
<?php
     $string = "Hello";                                      // the string which need to be toggled case
     $string_length = strlen($string);                      // calculate the string length
     for($i=0;$i<$string_length;$i++){                        // iterate to find ascii for each character
          $current_ascii = ord($string{$i});                 // convert to ascii code
          if($current_ascii>64 && $current_ascii<91){        // check for upper case character
                 $toggled_string .= chr($current_ascii+32);   // replace with lower case character
          }elseif($current_ascii>96 && $current_ascii<123){    // check for lower case character
                $toggled_string .= chr($current_ascii-32);   // replace with upper case character
          }else{
                $toggled_string .= $string{$i};               // concatenate the non alphabetic string.
              }
        }
     echo "The toggled case letter for $string is <hr />".$toggled_string; // output will be hELLO
?>
```

Hope this will help you

Same example is given in this [link](http://mydons.com/how-to-toggle-character-case-in-php-without-strlower-strupper-ucfirst-inbuilt-and-array-function/) .

Comment: Works just as expected, added benefit is that no Regex :) Will just indent and use it as-it-is.

Comment: Why people choose ugly code over simple one (as **@Nick** posted) ;s

Comment: Congrats!! Happy to help you.

Comment: @meze Its not Ugly, check same code, indented. Maybe Dhruvisha wrote it in hurry. (Not that I recommend, but I will use it like this:   http://codepad.org/FBWMww7W

Comment: @meze not ugly, and not faulty, like yours one. Check your code with ^ (Shift+6) it changes it to something else. http://codepad.org/nWb1WJIl

Comment: @Davinder forgot there's a gap. And deleted my previous solution. Then the code can be fixed and made even shorter: http://viper-7.com/G2Gal8

Answer (score 6):

To invert the case of a string I use this function:

```
function invert_case($string) {
  return preg_replace('/[a-z]/ie', '\'$0\' ^ str_pad(\'\', strlen(\'$0\'), \' \')', $string);
}
```

I found it in the [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php#55509) ages ago while I was looking to do the same thing. I just turned it into a function.

Comment: why is the replacement so complicated. Won't `"'\$0' ^ ' '"`  work??

Comment: Works, changes paSS#12wOrD to PAss#12WoRd, but I will favor @Dhruvisha 's answer for doing it without RegEx. Thanks anyway. Can't understand how it does without any kind of loop?

Comment: @Davinder the regex solution is cleaner and does the same in one line instead of 12 ;P

Comment: @meze Yeah cleaner & shorter, and it works, but I cant understand how it works.. Although I have noted it down.

Comment: I really don't see why you see non regex as a benefit. Regex solution does it much faster and in one line of code. Also, @meze `"'\$0' ^ ' '"` would work too, not entirely sure why the `str_pad`, etc was there - must be for a reason...

Comment: @Nick there is no benefit in no-Regex solution, the only thing is I find understanding Regex expressions very difficult. That said, I am going to use your solution in Production environment. Thats why I have noted down your code and voted it up.

Answer (score 2):

you need to explore `ctype_upper,ctype_lower` to find upper and lowercase letters in a string then you can use `strtolower and strtoupper` to change the case of letters.

Comment: The code is working with passwords made from A_Z, a-z 0-9. But passwords with punctuation symbols are not getting processed. I guess loosely both Ctype_upper & strtoupper do same work. ?

Comment: you want to get rid of symbols ?

Comment: ` $text = preg_replace("/(?![.=$'€%-])\p{P}/u", "", $text);
`

this will get all punctuations from your string

Comment: No, if in the loop, any symbol is encounterd in $pass, i need it to be appended as-it-is to $pass2

Comment: paSS#12wOrD to PAss#12WoRd My code is just working fine with numbers &  alphabets. But not with symbols.

Comment: you can use `ctype_punct()` which get all puncuations from your string

Comment: i think you might need to check this php manual

[http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php]

Comment: ok, but my issue is solved without checking the above link.. Without going throug 10+ functions.. Btw, there is an extra "]" in your link, resulting in Not-Found message on php.net..

Comment: i am glad you fond solution. but its always a good idea to explore a little for future and better understanding, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers to this question only work for a-z. This works for all unicode characters.

- ö -> Ö
- Å -> å
- ü -> Ü
- and so on

  ```
  function invert_case($str) {
      $inverted = '';
      for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($str);$i++) {
          $char = $str[$i];
          $upper = mb_strtoupper($char);
          if($upper == $char) {
              $inverted .= mb_strtolower($char);
          } else {
              $inverted .= $upper;
          }
      }
      return $inverted;
  }
  ```

Comment: Works, but only after removing mb_ from strten, strtoupper, strlower (atleast on codepad (with strict runtime environment)) http://codepad.org/7MUwFd2C

Answer (score 0):

Joakim's answer is on the right track but one line is wrong:
Replace `$char = $str[$i];` with `$char = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);`
Only then will it work for all unicode characters including German.